# Uniform integrability, Lebesgue Nikodym Theorem , Terrence Tao's Notes

Tags: integration, measure-theory

This problem was from [Corollary 1 of Lebesgue Nikodym Thorem](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/04/245b-notes-1-signed-measures-and-the-radon-nikodym-lebesgue-theorem/).

> Let $m$ be an usigned $\sigma$-finite measure, and let $\mu$ be a signed     $\sigma$-finite measure.
>
> 1. $\mu=m_f$ for some measurable $f$.  ($m_f := \int f \, dm $)
> 2. For any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|\mu(E)| < \varepsilon$ whenever $m(E) \le \delta$.

Prof Tao wrote 1 => 2. I looked at ex 11, and did the problem and I **needed absolutely integrability of $f$**.

I suppose $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu$ may help,  decomposing it to its components still does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: You indeed need some additional condition, as the example $f = \sum_n n 1_{(n,n+1)}$ with $m$ the usual Lebesgue measure, shows. In this case, the sigma finiteness conditions are clearly satisfied, but property (2) is not.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i think we need $\mu$ to be finite measure.

Comment: Yup, I have also commented on his post, asking this condition.